# Is there a way to take a google sheets workbook and be able to run a continuous timed loop that toggles between the tabs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I work in the Production Department for a large Roofing company. We have a large intake of jobs that I have been utilizing Google Sheets for. I have recently persuaded the rest of the department to use them as well. That being said I would like to take the workbook we are working out of and display that on a TV monitor. I have been searching for a way for the workbook to continuously toggle between the tabs while being displayed daily on this screen but have had no luck. Any and all help would be appreciated.

I did find through google that someone previously helped someone with their code but it's foreign to me and I actually couldn't locate that question/answer on here either.

The only thing I have tried was the code that someone else had used but was unsuccessful. This may be because it was listed in three different parts which I didn't understand.

Comment: `toggle between the tabs while being displayed daily on this screen` I have a thought that this might be an "XY" problem. Would you please explain why you need to do this? What information is on each page that you need to be _automatically_ switching between tabs?

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, the workbook is being used as intake for all the jobs we have coming in and information pertaining to each job. It's divided into tabs. We have two locations so there is a separate tab for each location and then there is a tab for outstanding jobs that we need to collect on and why it hasn't been collected. 3 tabs in total (at the moment)l. They want it on a monitor in the office at all times but would like to spend 5 mins per tab on a rotation all day.

Comment: Still some ambiguity: `They want it on a monitor` - this suggests `1)` a single monitor (mounted on a wall, etc?) devoted to cycle through the tabs; `2)` not running on user monitors otherwise it would interupt their data entry Have I got that right? On a tangent, I imagine that some tabs are contain a lot of data (rows and columns) _BUT_ the key data is found in several predictable fields. Have you considered a dashboard (or an alternative tab) that focuses on the key information rather than showing all (or part) of each tab?

Comment: Yes, it would be on a TV connected to a laptop. The sole purpose of this TV/monitor and laptop would be to have this spreadsheet to continuously play. To be honest the two tabs would be Columns A - O but the rows would be added to daily resulting in over 400 rows by the end of the year. Unfortunately a dashboard is out of the question as I've already suggested it. They want to see all the information on each tab (Minus all the rows at once). Everyone will have this spreadsheet on their computers and phones it's just something they want everyone to be able to see outside of our Production Dept.

Comment: With respect, can you see how the details of this scenario have changed significantly but imperceptively from the initial question? I still have questions: `over 400 rows by the end of the year` - a working definition of impractical (which I'm sure you know already; you have my sincere condolences);   `everyone to be able to see outside of our Production Dept.`  - this doesn't seem to be relevant to the scenario, except that I hope for your sake that most users are can "view" rather than "edit". Good luck

Comment: I appreciate all your time and effort helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display given sheets in a spreadsheet:

- on one computer (i.e. it should not disrupt users data entry)
- for 5 minutes each,
- running throughout the working day.

Try the Google Apps Script function below. It should be run from the laptop attached to the display screen; it should be executed manually. (It can't be triggered by a simple or installable triggers otherwise it will run on EVERY computer of every user.)

---

```
/*
// A script to display given sheets of a spreadsheet on a given laptop for 5 minutes each throughout the day
//
// EXECUTION: Rum the script on the laptop manually so that it does not interfere with other users.
//
// SHEETS: enter sheet names in array "sheets2Display"
// DISPLAY TIME PER SHEET: one minute=60,000 milliseconds, so set variable in "Utilies.sleep()" to 300,000 (5 minutes)
// LOOP VALUE: 
//  TIME to PROCESS: multiply number of sheets2Display by 5 minutes each = total time to loop through tabs
//  DAILY DURATION: assume start = 09:00, end = 17:00, duration = 8 hours *60 minutes = 480 minutes
//  NUMBER OF LOOPS: divide DAILY DURATION/ TIME TO PROCESS; edit as value of "NUMBER OF LOOPS
*/
function displaySheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // SHEETS: array of names of sheets to loop
  var sheets2Display = ["Master", "Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5"]

  // DISPLAYTIME
  var displayTime = 5000

  // LOOP VALUE:  
  var numberOfLoops = 2

  for (var loops = 0;loops<numberOfLoops;loops++){
    for (var i=0;i<sheets2Display.length;i++){
      var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets2Display[i]);
      Logger.log(sourceSheet.getName());
      sourceSheet.activate();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(displayTime);// pause in the loop for 10 seconds
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this script in? Is it JavaScript?

Comment: Google apps script - it is a subset of JavaScript. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#:~:text=You%20write%20code%20in%20modern,Calendar%2C%20Drive%2C%20and%20more.)